# org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Cannot commit, transaction is already closed - when batch insert

Tags: java, mybatis

I want to make batch insert into PostgreSQL using MyBatis (3.5.1). When I do commit on sqlSession I get an exception org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Cannot commit, transaction is already closed

Though inserting records one by one works ok.

I craete SqlSession with autocommit flag set to false.

mapper.xml

```
<insert id="saveAll" parameterType="com.test.Event"
            useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="id">
        INSERT INTO test.events (device_id, user_name)
        VALUES
        <foreach collection="events" item="event" separator=",">
            (#{event.deviceId}, #{event.username})
        </foreach>
</insert>
```

repository class

```
public void saveAll(List<Event> events) {
        try (SqlSession sqlSession = transactionManager.getSession()) {
            EventMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(EventMapper.class);
            mapper.saveAll(events);
        }
}
```

main

```
SqlSession sqlSession =  SqlSessionFactoryConfig.getFactory().openSession(false);
try {
     repository.saveAll(events);
     sqlSession.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
     LOGGER.info("Exception was occured.", ex);
     handleSqlSessionWhenException(sqlSession);
     throw ex;
} finally {
     handleSqlSession(sqlSession);
}
```

Stacktrace

```
Exception was occured.
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error committing transaction.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Cannot commit, transaction is already closed
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Cannot commit, transaction is already closed
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:226)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:217)
```

Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `saveAll` method closes the `SqlSession` and that ends the transaction.

This [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement invokes SqlSession.close` after the try block:

```
try (SqlSession sqlSession = transactionManager.getSession()) {
    EventMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(EventMapper.class);
    mapper.saveAll(events);
}
```

In order to solve this first of all you need to make sure that the same `SqlSession` is used. Depending on what exactly `transactionManager.getSession` does it may return not the same `SqlSession` as you get in the code that invokes `repository.saveAll`.

After you fix this and you do use the same session you need remove `try` block so that the session is not automatically closed.